# CS1061: Compilation Error Message

Tags: c#, asp.net

i have added a linkbutton to my page and get error when debugging says:

> CS1061: 'ASP.uilayer_test_aspx' does not contain a definition for 'lbl_Click' and no extension method 'lbl_Click' accepting a first argument of type 'ASP.uilayer_test_aspx' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

.aspx contains :

```
<asp:LinkButton ID="lbl" runat="server" OnClick="lbl_Click">LinkButton</asp:LinkButton>
```

page diretive :

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/UILayer/UI.Master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Test.aspx.cs" Inherits="WebApp.UILayer.Test" Title="Untitled Page" %>
```

.cs contains :

```
namespace WebApp.UILayer
{
    public partial class Test : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        private void lbl_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
        } 
    }
}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You have to make `lbl_Click` protected and not private.

The reason for this is that an own class, called like `ASP.uilayer_test_aspx` is created from the aspx source. This class *inherits* from your `Test` class. Private methods are not visible to child classes, so it has to be protected.

Comment: This one was a lifesaver ^^. It happens too if you have "internal "...this should be considered a bug, compiling fine but raising error with the published version....shouldnt the compiler warn about this visibility error?

Answer (score 1):

Because you have set the click handler `lbl_Click` modifier as `private`, you have to set it as `Protected` OR `Public`. Since the aspx file inherited the cs class, and private member can't be accessed.

This

```
 private void lbl_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
```

should be like..

```
 protected void lbl_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
```